# Proof of Forward Euler for discretizing a transfer function

Tags: z-transform, transfer-function, laplace-transform, discretization

In Levine book "The control handbook" it is shown that, for discretizing 
a transfer function $\frac{1}{s}$ using Forward Euler i simply have to replace s
with $\frac{z-1}{T}$. How can extend the proof and show that the substitution works for
every possible transfer function $G(s)$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? Of course you can replace $s$ by that function and see what you get. It is just one out of several ways to discretize a continuous system. There are other transformations (such as backward Euler) that will guarantee that a stable system transforms to a stable system. That is not the case with forward Euler.

Comment: I don't understand what's the proof for the subtitution, to me laplace and z-transform are completely different things, so i don't understand why is the correct to apply that substitution. In my textbook, the proof is derived from a particular case, and i would like to generalize it. (Levine - The Control Handbook. Volume 1 pag 283)

Comment: Does my answer clarify things a bit?

Comment: Read [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24103/4298) to see that the Laplace and Z-transforms are very much related. The Z-transform is in the discrete domain what the Laplace transform is in the continuous domain.

Comment: @MattL., maybe here my doubt is more clear .... https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63229/derive-the-forward-euler-substitution-for-transfer-function

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see how the forward Euler method approximates a continuous-time system is by considering the "ideal" mapping of the $s$-plane to the $z$-plane ([why?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24103/4298)):

$$z=e^{sT}\tag{1}$$

For frequencies that are much smaller than the sampling frequency (i.e., $|s|T\ll 1$) we can approximate $e^{sT}$ by its first order Taylor series:

$$z\approx 1+sT\tag{2}$$

which is exactly the forward Euler mapping, resulting in

$$s=\frac{z-1}{T}\tag{3}$$